# C# Implementation of Unix crypt using System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, des

Overlooking the weak security provided by DES, I'm looking for a C# implementation of the Unix crypt() function that uses classes/methods in the .net framework's Cryptography namespace.

I found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9183/A-C-implementation-of-Unix-crypt

But I'm wondering if there's a shorter solution using `DESCryptoServiceProvider`, etc.

Comment: probably the .Net framework developers could not bring themselves to implement something so insecure :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both traditional and extended DES crypt salting permute the result of the [expansion function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES_supplementary_material#Expansion_function_.28E.29). For every bit i set in the salt, they swap bits i and i+24 of the expansion function result.

Because this occurs mid-round, unless the salt is zero (meaning no permutation occurs), it is not possible to use the framework cryptography.

Still, reimplementing DES doesn't take more than a kilobyte or two. My [CryptSharp](http://www.zer7.com/software.php?page=cryptsharp) library implements traditional and extended DES, MD5, SHA256, SHA512, and bcrypt algorithms. For the MD5 and both [SHA crypt](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) methods (methods $1$, $5$, and $6$), it uses the framework cryptography. If you aren't bound to using the DES crypt method, take a look at ShaCrypter.cs -- it's fairly short.

Comment: Well done with CryptSharp. I just wish it was a bit faster. I guess that's the .net framework kicking in. I ran jtr (john the ripper) on the same machine with much much higher performance.

Comment: I tried to use CryptSharp `Crypter.TraditionalDes.Crypt(pwd,salt);`. I need to use a 4 digit salt but it says  "Invalid salt." - what are the requirements for the salt?

Comment: The DES salt is 12 bit -- 2 characters of a variant of Base64 called "B64" (., /, 0-9, A-Z, and lastly a-z). CryptSharp can generate the salt, or CryptSharp.Utility.Base64Encoding.UnixCrypt can encode from bytes for you. You could use numbers from 1-4095. (Not 0-4095... A salt of 0 is equivalent to a salt of 1.) If you need a stronger salt, you will need to use a stronger method -- that's all there is for traditional DES.

Answer (score 4):

An implementation of Unix crypt you mentioned is rather slow.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/aannenko/d47c90b0f92177286bb9814850888920) is a standalone lightweight and pretty efficient implementation of crypt(3) written in C# that leverages [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1) type to hold and transform data.